# Firebase child_added snapshot

Tags: edit, firebase, addchild

Started getting to grips with Firebase, but I am confused about one thing.  I add data to my Firebase in the correct way - `.set()`.  That's OK, I create a list view using `.on('child_added'...` what I then need to do is update the item added, can do that with `.update()` , but the `.on('child_added'...` then displays the update again.  How do you prevent this?

OK an edit .... This is the code that adds to the Firebase

```
function s4() {
return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
.toString(16)
.substring(1);
};

function guid() {
return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

jQuery('#submit_action').click(function(){
var profile_id = guid();
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/list");
myDataRef.push({ name: profile_id });
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/actions/"+profile_id);
jQuery('.left input,.left textarea,.left select').each(function(){
var value  = jQuery(this).val();
var field  = jQuery(this).attr('name');
myDataRef.child(field).set(value);
});
myDataRef.child('red').set('0');
});
```

And this does actually read the "reply"

```
var listRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/list");
listRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
var msgData = snapshot.val();
jQuery.each(msgData, function(k, v){
var actRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/list/"+k);
actRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
var aData = snapshot.val();
var bRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/actions/"+aData.name);
var bData = '';
bRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
bData = snapshot.val();
// NEED TO REFRESH AND APPEND TEXT TO A DIV
});
});
});
})
```

BUT if I append it always "duplicates" - obviously I only want to show the return once as a simple "list"

Comment: Please add the code you tried.

Comment: Hi Narendra, OK, my code has changed a bit because I have been trying to get the right format back out, but have added it above

Comment: Child_added doesn't appear anywhere in your code. When using `value`, you get an update any time the data at that path (including its children) is modified. This looks to be per spec.